# How to import blob field to hive and then read it out

Tags: blob, sqoop

The enviorment:

- Hive=1.1.0
- Sqoop=1.4.6

We've tried to use sqoop to import blob field(jpg files) to hive.
We've tried:

1. --map-java-column oracle_blob_column_name=string
2. --map-java-column oracle_blob_column_name=binary
3. --map-column-hive oracle_blob_column_name=string
4. --map-column-hive oracle_blob_column_name=binary

We've tried the following ways to retrieve the blob content and write the jpg files to local:

1. getBinaryStream()
2. getString()

None of the combination above worked.

Has anyone managed to use sqoop to import blob field from RDBMS to Hive, then read it out from Hive successfully?